# SQL search for string containing characters

Tags: sql

I have a string `"abc"`, and I want to search, in a SQL table, for the values that contain either a, b or c.

This is what I have right now:

```
Select * from TABLE where NAME like "abc" ;
```

This didn't work, but I know if I try something like

```
where Name like "a" or Name like "b" or ....
```

it will work.

Is there an easier way to do this?
Since I don't want to separate my string into characters.

Comment: only like 'string' will not work for contains, you need to put inside `%%`

Comment: Select * from TABLE where NAME like "%abc%" ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression for this.
Have a look at the following :

```
Select * from TABLE where NAME REGEXP "[abc]";
```

Answer (score 2):

select * from ab where name REGEXP '[abc]'

Answer (score -2):

This will do

```
Select * from TABLE where NAME like "%abc%" ;
```

For more check information here http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

Comment: this will give only the text containing abc like asdfabcasdf, but will not give adgs